# Unenforced foreign key for Django model?

Tags: django-models, foreign-keys

Is there a way of making something which behaves like a ForeignKey (i.e. being able to access the other object) but which isn't enforced?

i.e. if the foreign key table (ModelOne) didn't have a matching value, `ModelMany.modelone` would just return `None`.

I don't want the database to be aware of the link in any way (other than perhaps adding an index to speed up retrieval, if the ModelOne linking field isn't `id`.)

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=False,null=False,unique=True,validators=[validate_tag])
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=False,null=False,unique=True)
    ...

class ModelMany(models.Model):
    # imei should be some form of "weak" ForeignKey relation to ModelOne's imei
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=False,null=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=12,choices=EVENT_TYPE_CHOICES)
    ...
```

The reason for needing this is that I have two two tables which are filled independently.  The data may arrive in the ModelMany table minutes or hours before a matching row arrives in the ModelOne table.